# Gazebo crashes when spawning a robot with urdf

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I've already asked in ros answer but didn't received any answer (http://answers.ros.org/question/168156/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-a-robot-with-urdf/). Thus, I try it here again.

I'm looking forward to use ROS Indigo with the fresh released Ubuntu 14.04. Gazebo is starting fine but instantly crashes when spawning a robot via service call:

```
(indigo) alex@ThinkPad-T440p:~/hector$ rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.921875] [0.000000] Loading model xml from file
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.922486] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.924802] [0.000000] Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

Lets Gazebo crash without any message:

```
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 14649, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/alex/.ros/log/cdde1b80-e1a0-11e3-ab05-5c514ff707c4/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/alex/.ros/log/cdde1b80-e1a0-11e3-ab05-5c514ff707c4/gazebo-1*.log
```

I've just tested it with Gazebo 2.2.2 (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros) using "empty_world" and the Baxter robot urdf (see gazebosim.org /Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models, sry not enough Karma for links ;)).

Has anybody encountered this issue too?

kind regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6360/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-a-robot-with-urdf./) by [a_stumpf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/804/a_stumpf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/826/gary-servin/) on 2014-06-06**:
Hi, this issue was reported in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/63/gzsdf-segfaults-in-trusty and followed https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4633

**Comment by [a_stumpf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/804/a_stumpf/) on 2014-06-20**:
This issue is discussed at ros answers too: http://answers.ros.org/question/168156/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-a-robot-with-urdf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

An issue is linked in the comment above.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2014-06-15**:
I am still interested in the bug fix!